# creating an observable from transporter.sendMail

Tags: node.js, observable, nodemailer, rxjs5

i am trying to create an observable from sendMail, currently my test for that looks like that:

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/index.d.ts" />
import * as chai from "chai";
let assert = chai.assert;
const Rx = require('rxjs');
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

describe("emailPlugin", function() {
   it.only('should emit one value from a callback', function () {
       let mailOptions = {
          from: '"Fred Foo " <MY@gmail.com>', // sender address
          to: 'YOUR@gmail.com', // list of receivers; comma seperated
          subject: 'Hello ✔', // Subject line
          text: 'Hello world ', // plaintext body
          html: '<b>Hello world </b>' // html body
      };
      let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport('smtps://MY%40gmail.com:MY@smtp.gmail.com');

      let boundCallback = Rx.Observable.bindNodeCallback(transporter.sendMail);
      boundCallback(mailOptions, function(error, info){
          if(error){
              return error;
          }
          return info.response;
      }).subscribe(x => console.log(x), e => console.error(e));
  });   
});
```

the result is an error:

`[TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object]`

can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem as you, I found this fixed it. Instead of:

```
let boundCallback = Rx.Observable.bindNodeCallback(transporter.sendMail);
```

This works for me:

```
let boundCallback = Rx.Observable.bindNodeCallback((options: any, callback: any) => {
  return transporter.sendMail(options, callback);
});
```

I have no idea why, it seems to me the original form should be correct. Looks like TypeScript struggles with the type of the `sendMail` function. Hope that helps!